# Approximately how many developer hours have been spent on Monero so far?

Tags: development

For the purposes of this question please include research from the [Monero Research Labs](https://lab.getmonero.org/) and any time preparing the work that is visible in [GitHub](https://lab.getmonero.org/) today.

Itemization of estimated hours for each focus (RingCT, LMDB, Kovri, GUI, etc) would be ideal but is not necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is really hard to tell, but here are a few things we know:

- In April of 2015 smooth estimated that there was a rough estimate of [two to three full time equivalents](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=753252.msg11189553#msg11189553) working on Monero software development, testing, and research reports. For clarity, this estimate varies over time.
- moneromooo spent at least 710 hours (https://forum.getmonero.org/9/work-in-progress/2410/a-continuation-for-all-purpose-programming-of-what-needs-to-get-done-in-monero, https://forum.getmonero.org/22/completed-tasks/334/fund-a-developer-moneromoo-will-work-part-time-on-monero-for-260-hours-over-approx-6-months)
- Ilya spent some amount of 280 hours on the GUI (https://forum.getmonero.org/9/work-in-progress/2476/the-official-qt-gui-project), there is some item list in the thread.
- other tasks in that forum may or may not mention smaller chunks of time.

This is start to give an idea maybe, but I doubt it can be made into a reasonably accurate estimation.